# str_replace after preg_match hangs PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, str-replace

I am trying to retrieve a value from a returned header:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2015 00:48:51 GMT Server: Apache X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.8 Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Set-Cookie: frontend=b09kg96q756cv2a08l9d6vbq07; expires=Mon, 08-Jun-2015 01:48:52 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=***-shop.***.nl; HttpOnly Location: http://commercive-shop.declaredemo.nl/commshopengine/index.php/customer/account/ X-Powered-By: PleskLin Content-Length: 0 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

i do this with a regular expression and clean it up with str_replace. However PHP hangs after this code and seems to go in some endless loop:

```
preg_match('/frontend=(.+); expires=/i', $output, $matches);
$sid = str_replace("frontend=","", $matches[0]);
```

I can echo the value $matches[0] which returns the expected value

```
frontend=scrcc1lhh01gdss5m6ala8n791; expires=
```

but I can not str_replace the value. I want to strip frontend= and ; expires= from the string and keep scrcc1lhh01gdss5m6ala8n791.

I am using PHP 5.6

Comment: Just echo the preg_match value will return: frontend=scrcc1lhh01gdss5m6ala8n791; expires=

Comment: lost to see the problem here

Comment: Please add your current output from your code and also add your expected output from this code here (@Dagon You're not alone here :)

Comment: lost together @Rizier123 - we could cuddle for warmth -)

Comment: @CoenPonsen Now we are making progress here! We have your input, we see what your current output from `$matches[0]` is. But now is the question what do you expect to get/what do you want?

Comment: Your code works - [Demo](http://www.tehplayground.com/#msJLnXOrI)

Comment: You don't have `scrcc1lhh01gdss5m6ala8n791` anywhere in your input. Something is weird here

Comment: why did somebody -1 ed me :(

Comment: because the question was poorly asked

Comment: well i edited right away, i'm coding for weeks straight now.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your `preg_match()` call with a `preg_replace()` call and replace the entire string with the id, e.g.

```
echo $sid = preg_replace('/.*frontend=(.+); expires=.*/i', "$1", $str);
```

output:

```
b09kg96q756cv2a08l9d6vbq07
```

Or just don't use `$matches[0]` as @Dagon already pointed out in the comments and just use: `$matches[1]`.

Comment: or keep current code and just echo `$matches[1]` skipping the string replace

Comment: @Dagon That would be too mainstream :D

Answer (score -1):

This will return the correct value.

```
preg_match('/frontend=(.+); expires=/i', $output, $matches);
$search  = array('expires=', ';', 'frontend=');
$replace = $matches;

$sid = str_replace($search,"", $replace);
echo $sid[0]. '<br>'.'<br>';
echo $sid[1];
```

Comment: cant imagine why you would provide a bad answer several hours after a good one was accepted.

Comment: I didn't realize we were in a competition, should I check with you before every post?

Comment: Yes. If you plan to keep posting one's of this quality

Comment: His question references 'str_replace' several times. The title of his post alludes to a problem when using 'str_replace after preg_match'.  The answer you provided did not use that particular function.